# Delete row from database with form in the same page

Tags: php

In the same page I have a form that asks the user to confirm whether he wants to delete the data or not, and I have the PHP code. Now, I want to delete a row from database using superglobals, but I can't figure out the problem. It always echos "NOT DELETED". Also If the user chooses not to delete, I would like to perform a redirect to `home.php`.

```
<body>

<h2>Are you sure you want to delete the student?</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="YES" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="NO" />
</form>

<?php

$fields = array('id', 'student', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email');
$student= array();

foreach ($fields as $field) {
$student[$field]="";
}

if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);
}
else if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    if(!empty($id)) {   

    include "inc_DBConnect.php";

    $SQLString = "DELETE FROM students WHERE id = '$id'";

    $SQLQueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnection, $SQLString);
    if($SQLQueryResult === FALSE) {
        echo "<p>There was an error retrieving the record.<br />\n</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Student deleted</p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "NOT DELETED";
 }


}

?>
</body>
```

Comment: most likely because you are not doing `POST` request. Not sure what prevents you from using `var_dump()` or `print_r()` and check that yourself first instead of elaborating things here.

Comment: do a print of $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; and also where does the variable id come from? because i cannot see it on your form. I assumed it would have been a hidden field or something

Comment: your form shows no "id" (var or input) that you try to re-use after that... where do $_POST['id'] or $_GET['id'] come from ?

Comment: They come from a another file, I attached the id to a link. If I delete straight from the link, it works, but I want to do it from the same page using superglobal

Comment: as it's been said by others, perform a $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] + echo your $id (if not empty) and you'll have more info.

Comment: The method is a GET and the id is ok. It deletes the data straight away without waiting for the user to click the button

Answer (score 0):

Try to print your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` variable before if

OR `var_dump($_SERVER)` and check what's wrong in this array - maybe your server don't set a REQUEST_METHOD key.

By other ways you should also try this way

```
if( count($_POST) ){/*....*/};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is no id field there so would not going to get it on POST request.

```
<body>
<?php 
// check this too when your form is submitting
// print_r($_SERVER); 
?>
<h2>Are you sure you want to delete the student?</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="YES" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="NO" />
</form>

<?php

$fields = array('id', 'student', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email');
$student= array();

foreach ($fields as $field) {
$student[$field]="";
}

if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);
}
else if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    if(!empty($id)) {   

    include "inc_DBConnect.php";

    $SQLString = "DELETE FROM students WHERE id = '$id'";

    $SQLQueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnection, $SQLString);
    if($SQLQueryResult === FALSE) {
        echo "<p>There was an error retrieving the record.<br />\n</p>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>Student deleted</p>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "NOT DELETED";
}
}

?>
</body>
```

Comment: The issue is that this code does not get beyond the server request method line. First thing to find out is what that line returns. Is it a POST, GET etc